# Using subclass as both parameter and return type in abstract method

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class, abstract

I am trying to use an abstract class and make all the extensions of it to pass a subclass to a method and return the same. It is better explainable via code only.

```
public abstract class AbstractRequestReBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private CreditCardUpdateProcessor creditCardUpdateProcessor;

    abstract BookingRequest rebuildRequest(BookingRequest request);

    public BillingDetails updateCard(BillingDetails billingDetails) {
        return creditCardUpdateProcessor.updateCreditCardInBillingDetails(billingDetails);
    }

}
```

```java
@Component
public class HotelRequestReBuilder extends AbstractRequestReBuilder {

    public HotelBookingRequest rebuildRequest(HotelBookingRequest request) {
        BillingDetails billingDetails = request.getBillingDetails();
        BillingDetails modifiedBillingDetails = updateCard(billingDetails);
        request.setBillingDetails(modifiedBillingDetails);
        return request;
    }
}
```

where

```java
public class HotelBookingRequest extends BookingRequest<RoomDetail> implements Serializable {
}
```

Currently I am getting a compiler error saying `rebuildRequest` is not implemented in `HotelRequestReBuilder`. Can anyone please check and let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HotelRequestReBuilder.rebuildRequest(HotelBookingRequest)` does not override `AbstractRequestReBuilder.rebuildRequest(BookingRequest)`, it overloads it.

The easiest solution is to make `HotelBookingRequest` a type parameter of `AbstractRequestReBuilder`:

```
public abstract class AbstractRequestReBuilder<B extends BookingRequest<...>> {
    abstract B rebuildRequest(B request);
}
```

And implement it using:

```
public class HotelRequestReBuilder extends AbstractRequestReBuilder<HotelBookingRequest> {

    public HotelBookingRequest rebuildRequest(HotelBookingRequest request) {
        BillingDetails billingDetails = request.getBillingDetails();
        BillingDetails modifiedBillingDetails = updateCard(billingDetails);
        request.setBillingDetails(modifiedBillingDetails);
        return request;
    }
}
```

This will resolve your compile-time problems. Just note that you need to use the appropriate type parameter for `BookingRequest<...>` that fits the abstraction level of `AbstractRequestReBuilder`